# I'm following a course on sculpting, but for some reason the retopologized version of my fish is showing up in front of the sculpted model. Why?

Tags: sculpting, retopology

I'd first noticed this whenever the guy doing the tutorial had re-enabled the old model's eyes in order to continue sculpting with the eyes visible. I had turned the visibility of the eyes back on, but they didn't show up. I selected it to see the outline, and its there, but only visible on sections where the re-topologized fish is not obstructing it. As shown in the picture below, it's there and very much in front of the fish, but acting very strangely. As an example of what I'm talking about, the right eye of the fish is there and in it's socket but because the model is there it's not showing. I'm pretty sure this is a weird setting I enabled but I don't really know what it could be. For reason I thought I had turned off back face culling, but it's on and I don't really think it would effect it anyways.
[image]

[image]

This second example is much more clear than just seeing the eye. Here I moved the new fish model inside of the old one, but it's still showing up in front and the eyes are still not fully visible.

Comment: Looks like you enabled "In front" in the viewport display properties. Select the culprit object and click on the orange square icon in the properties editor, then go to viewport display panel and uncheck "In front"

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it. It was driving me crazy since I didn't know how to google this question. Thanks again!